# Can I specify a column to be used BEFORE looping through files in a folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've got a ridiculous number of Excel files in which I need to convert data in one measurement unit to another. I've got code to do the conversion, I've got code to loop through files in a folder, and I've got code to have the user choose the column the data is in. This last is important, because the data is from multiple sources and I don't really want them to have to use a different macro for every single source.

So what I'd like to be able to do is 
1) Specify the columns the data's in
2) Loop through all the files in a given folder (which should all be from the same source, so the data will be in the same column) and run the conversions I need (which I have code for).

At the moment I have this mess in VBA:

```
' Change solar data from W/m2 to MJ/m2 and get daily sums

' Set up for the loop

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

' Optimize Macro Speed

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Retrieve Target Folder Path From User

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder With Your Text Files"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel

NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")

myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

' Attempt to have user select column for use

Dim ReturnValue
Set ReturnValue = Application.InputBox("Type the column your solar data is in, e.g. A:A", "Data Select", Type:=8)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder

Do While myFile <> ""

' Open the workbook

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=(myPath & myFile)

'Set variable equal to opened workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code

    DoEvents

'Convert W/m2 to MJ/m2

    ReturnValue.Offset(, 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Dim col As Long
    col = ReturnValue.Column + 1
    Cells(1, col).FormulaR1C1 = "MJ/m2"
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(LastRow, col))
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=-99.9, -99.9, (RC[-1]*0.086344))" '<-- this formula needs to be divided by 24 if you're starting with a daily sum of hourly averages

 'Sum every 24 hours

    ReturnValue.Offset(, 2).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Dim col2 As Long
    col2 = ReturnValue.Column + 2
    Cells(1, col2).FormulaR1C1 = "MJ/m2/d"
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(25, col2), Cells(LastRow, col2))
    rng2 = "=IF(MOD(ROW(R[-1]C),24)=0, SUM(R[-23]C[-1]:R[-1]C[-1]), """")"

'Save and Close Workbook

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code

    DoEvents

'Get next file name

    myFile = Dir
 Loop
```

I assume the error is in where I placed the InputBox code, but I can't figure out where to put it without having to have the user specify the column for EVERY SINGLE FILE. Which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

This is for handing off to an undergrad intern at my job, so needs to be fairly straightforward.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would help to know what the problem is, exactly. (where do you get the error?) You will want to [avoid using activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad @cybernetic.nomad At the moment, it appears to be breaking at the formula in the first conversion:
` rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=-99.9, -99.9, (RC[-1]*0.086344))"" `

I've re-coded to 
`Dim rng As Range`
`Set rng = wb.Worksheets("Hourly").Range(Cells(2, nextcol), Cells(LastRow, nextcol))`

Which will grab the right column if I use the dreaded 'select' to check it, but if I attempt the formula it either selects rows below the data and 14 columns wide, or fails entirely with a 1004 error.

Comment: Looks like it works fine for me as long as I have something in column `A`. Try changing `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` so it finds the last row in the range selected by the user? It would be helpful to have sample data

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That worked! I've no idea why, but it did.

Example data is pretty simply summarized as columns date, time, temp, solar radiation (watts), precipitation, but different sources are not in that order. Hourly data for a year, so 8000+ columns--and I'll admit I'm too new to this to know how to attach it to the questions.

Thanks again!